# Allow colon in Django urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to write urls rule for `http://localhost:8000/api/http://www.google.com/`

which is `url(r'^api/(?P<url>(:\d+)+[.\w]+)/$', 'qlu_app.views.api', name='api'),`

But it is not working ..Can some one please help me.

Comment: How do you kniw the semicolon is the problem? What's "not working" mean? What error are you seeing?

Comment: That's a colon, not a semicolon.

Comment: Why do you have a `\d+` in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
url(r'^api/(?P<url>[:\/\.\w]+)/$', 'qlu_app.views.api', name='api'),
```